# Logging in an application

Tags: c#, wpf, logging, trace

I built an application and want to use logging in my application before giving it out to a user to know the actions the user did in case before any error.
 I haven't used logging before, so I did a bit of study to find out good methods for the same and perhaps `Trace` class in .NET looks like what might help in this scenario.
Using a text file seems to be a better idea here for the logging setting a `TextWriterTraceListener` in the `App.Config` file of my project, and using in the code `Trace.Writeline("Error info", "Field");`

1) Even after reading good amount of content, I am not sure about good approaches for logging? 
Should there be different error logger and information logging files? 
How does logging work for specifying different types of error (such as warning, critical, error etc.?)

2) I want to use the same logfile in one of my other projects in the solution. So, do I add the same `Trace Listener` section in the `App.Config` of my project?

Comment: Check out the very good and well documented log4net project: http://logging.apache.org/log4net/

Comment: +1 log4net.  Very good full-featured logger with multiple severity levels, custom appenders, etc.

Comment: Did you actually try researching this ? There are great resources available in the search resutls for ".net logging" or "C# logging". It would have taken less effort to type that than to type out a big SO question.

Comment: @Robotsushi: Read from MSDN documentation. Can you point to some good links which could make things more clear?

Comment: If you can use Log4Net do that, if not use Enterprise library. Neither one is very difficult to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a logging library (such as log4net), you can do all the things you are asking about easily.  You can set up your logging in a config file to go to event log, file, console, etc (or any combination) and set the logging levels independently.

That is, you can say the file will have informationals, warnings, errors, and fatals, but the event log will log only the errors and fatals.

In general, nearly all of the logging libraries have these features.  The examples below are just in terms of log4net but the same concepts apply to most logging libraries...

To get the logger in any class in your solution, you just need to ask for a logger in your class:

```
public MyClass
{
    private static readonly ILog _log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyClass));

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        _log.Debug("This is a debug message.");
        _log.Info("This is an informational message.");
        _log.Warn("This is a warning message.");
        _log.Error("This is an error message.");
        _log.Fatal("This is a fatal message.");
    }
}
```

In addition, you can filter based on the loggers, that is, you could suppress log messages from paraticular classes or only display logging messages for a subset of classes, etc.

A sample config settings block would look like this.  This creates a rolling file appender (keeps several days worth of logs) and Console appender

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="c:\logs\AgentLog"/>
        <appendToFile value="true"/>
        <datePattern value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <rollingStyle value="Date"/>
        <MaxSizeRollBackups value="14"/>
        <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="false"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%d{HH:mm:ss.fff} [%thread] %-5level %logger{1} - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="ColoredConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender">
        <mapping>
            <level value="FATAL"/>
            <foreColor value="Yellow"/>
            <backColor value="Red, HighIntensity"/>
        </mapping>
        <mapping>
            <level value="ERROR"/>
            <foreColor value="Red, HighIntensity"/>
        </mapping>
        <mapping>
            <level value="WARN"/>
            <foreColor value="Yellow, HighIntensity"/>
        </mapping>
        <mapping>
            <level value="INFO"/>
            <foreColor value="Green, HighIntensity"/>
        </mapping>
        <mapping>
            <level value="DEBUG"/>
            <foreColor value="White"/>
        </mapping>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%d{HH:mm:ss.fff} [%thread] %-5level %logger{1} - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
        <appender-ref ref="ColoredConsoleAppender"/>
    </root>
</log4net>
```

Comment: Sorry that I didn't mention earlier that I cannot use external libraries in my project. Is there a good approach I could follow without this as asked in my original post?

Comment: How does your workplace define external libraries?  Anything non-Microsoft?  What if it's a Microsoft add-on library?

Comment: I could definitely have a look at the Microsoft add-on library, but using anything external still takes time for getting permission. That is why I insisted on starting with .NET `Trace` class for this small application

Comment: Well log4net is appache, it's completely free.  If you can only go the MS route, you should check out the Enterprise Library, it has application blocks for Logging, etc.   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648951.aspx

Comment: @user1240679, Log4Net is far, far, easier to use than Enterprise Library. Get permission to use it.

Comment: @DourHighArch I completely agree, but if for some reason his hands are tied...  it is an option.  I'd hope they could standardize on log4net though, very, very easy to use.